# C build error "Expected int(*)[10] but argument is of type 'int'"

Tags: c, matrix

I am working on a C program that will find the sum of the diagonal elements of a matrix. One function in the program is supposed to print the matrix, but I cannot get the program to compile because of the error listed in the title. The code for the function is as follows

```
    void print_matrix(int A[10][10], int a)
        {
            int i, j ;
            printf("The matrix entered is\n") ;
            for ( i = 0 ; i < a ; i++)
                { for ( j = 0 ; j < a ; j++)
                   printf("\t%d", A[i][j]) ;
                }
         }
```

The error reads "expected 'int (*)[10]' but argument is of type 'int'"
I have tried to change the parameter to read print_matrix(int (*)[10], int a) and the same error is output. Using print_matrix(int A[][10], int a) also gives the same error. I have been unable to find what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have your matrix:

```
 int A[10][10] = { ... };
```

You should call the function like this:

```
 print_matrix( A, 10 );
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot could you explain what the problem was?

Comment: I suspect you were calling it like this: `print_matrix(A[10][10], 10)`.  That would try to access the integer stored at (10,10) and pass that as the first parameter.